# How to display the rendered entity of a store in a Drupal code?

Tags: php, drupal, modal-dialog, drupal-8, drupal-modules

I created a custom module for Drupal 8 and Drupal Commerce. It is used to display a link "Accept the conditions of sale" in the purchase funnel during an order.

This link displays a modal window with the rendering of a page.

I have created a "terms and conditions" display mode in my store types. I want the link to show the store's rendered "terms and conditions" entity in a modal window.

So I want to make the entity store instead of showing a page in the modal link.

How to do this ?

Here is my code :

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\commerce_marketplace_terms_and_conditions\Plugin\Commerce\CheckoutPane;

use Drupal\Component\Serialization\Json;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
use Drupal\commerce_checkout\Plugin\Commerce\CheckoutPane\CheckoutPaneBase;
use Drupal\commerce_checkout\Plugin\Commerce\CheckoutPane\CheckoutPaneInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Link;
use Drupal\Core\Url;

/**
 * Provides the completion message pane.
 *
 * @CommerceCheckoutPane(
 *   id = "marketplace_terms_and_conditions",
 *   label = @Translation("Marketplace Terms and Conditions"),
 *   default_step = "review",
 * )
 */
class MarketplaceTermsAndConditions extends CheckoutPaneBase implements CheckoutPaneInterface {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function buildPaneForm(array $pane_form, FormStateInterface $form_state, array &$complete_form) {
    $store_name = $this->order->getStore()->getName();
    $store_id = $this->order->getStoreId();
    $pane_form['#attached']['library'][] = 'core/drupal.dialog.ajax';
    $attributes = [
      'attributes' => [
        'class' => 'use-ajax',
        'data-dialog-type' => 'modal',
        'data-dialog-options' => Json::encode([
          'width' => 'auto'
        ]),
      ],
    ];
    $link = Link::fromTextAndUrl(
      $this->t('terms and conditions of the store "@store_name"', ['@store_name' => $store_name]),
      Url::fromUri("internal:/store/$store_id/cgv", $attributes)
    )->toString();
    $pane_form['marketplace_terms_and_conditions'] = [
      '#type' => 'checkbox',
      '#default_value' => FALSE,
      '#title' => $this->t('I have read and accept @terms.', ['@terms' => $link]),
      '#required' => TRUE,
      '#weight' => $this->getWeight(),
    ];
    return $pane_form;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The EntityTypeManager can be used to load and render entities, for most cases. Here are some different ways to do that in a [previous post](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/178434/how-do-i-render-nodes-now-that-node-view-has-been-deprecated). Just note that entityManager is deprecated, and you can use \Drupal::entityTypeManager().

In this case, the entity type is "commerce_store". So something like this would work inside a commerce pane (change 'default' to the name of your display mode).

```
  $entityMgr = \Drupal::entityTypeManager();
  $store = $entityMgr->getStorage("commerce_store")->load($storeId);

  if ($store) {
    $viewBuilder = $entityMgr->getViewBuilder('commerce_store');
    $pane_form['store'] = $viewBuilder->view($store, 'default');
  }
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm new to code. I took the code of my question from a contrib module. I personalized it with a link but finally I want a display. I understood your answer but where should I put this in my code to display the display mode in a modal ?

Comment: Personally, I find it easier to add an element like that to the page by default, and use CSS to hide it. Then have a button that shows it on the page. You can add the Javascript part in the pane itself, or as a theme library that is attached to the pane. Commerce has some good documentation if you haven't seen it: https://docs.drupalcommerce.org/commerce2/developer-guide/checkout/create-custom-checkout-pane

Comment: My module works https://ibb.co/fk0ZYPg and https://ibb.co/hVZj6sV. The link makes the cgv page of my code. I put the cgv page back by the store rendered entity with the "cgv" display mode. Can you make an answer with the code of my question. Thank you very much.